# Can't get my word randomizer script to loop properly

Tags: javascript, random, words

I'm trying to get this script to run, than end on the word Awesome. and then loop again/repeat.

Here's the JS

```js
var i, word, rnd, words, fadeSpeed, timer;

words = ['respected​.', 'essential.', 'tactical.', 'effortless.', 'credible.', 'smart.', 'engaging.', 'focused.', 'effective.', 'clear.', 'relevant.', 'strategic.', 'trusted.', 'compelling.', 'admired.', 'inspiring.', 'cogent.', 'impactful.', 'valued.'];

fadeSpeed = 500;
timer = 2000;

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i === 19) {
        word = 'awesome.';
        rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        word = words[rnd];
        words.splice(rnd, 1);
    } else {
        rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        word = words[rnd];
        words.splice(rnd, 1);
    }

    (function(word) {
        $('h1.random em').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
                $(this).html(word);
            })
            .slideDown('slow')
            .delay(timer)
            .fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    })(word);
}
```

Here's a link to the dev site.

http://dev-pivot-website.pantheon.io/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splice will remove word from your array .

```
words.splice(rnd, 1);
```

After the 20th element there is nothing left to iterate.

As @Jamiec said you will need a continuous loop.  You can also use setTimeout(); to loop continuously (should be less CPU heavy than while(true) )

Try something like this (slightly modified version of @jamiec's answer)

```
   var i, word, rnd, words, fadeSpeed, timer;

function getWords(){
var words = ['respected​.', 'essential.', 'tactical.', 'effortless.', 'credible.', 'smart.', 'engaging.', 'focused.', 'effective.', 'clear.', 'relevant.', 'strategic.', 'trusted.', 'compelling.', 'admired.', 'inspiring.', 'cogent.', 'impactful.', 'valued.'];
    return words;
}

words = getWords();
fadeSpeed = 500;
timer = 2000;

displayWords();



function displayWords(){
  var word;
  if(words.length == 0){
      word = "awesome.";  
      words = getWords();      
  }
  else{
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    word = words[rnd];
    words.splice(rnd, 1);
  }

  (function(word) {
        $('h1.random em').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
                $(this).html(word);
            })
            .slideDown('slow')
            .delay(timer)
            .fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    })(word);

    setTimeout(displayWords,1000);
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/198ke25u/3/

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked perfectly. adding that displayWords function was a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

In the

```
if(i===19)
```

case, you're setting

```
word= 'awesome.';
```

and then promptly writing over it without using it:

```
word= words[rnd];
```

Remove that last line (and the rnd= line above it, which will then become redundant).

Comment: I got rid of 
     words.splice(rnd, 1);
But it's still not working.

Comment: but than the script stops at iteration 19 - writes Awesome. and won't repeat.

Comment: splice will remove elements from array, you will need to repopulate the words array again after 'Awesome' is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have this continuously loop, seeing as you're removing from the array each time (presumably so you dont get duplicates in each sequence) you will need to do a few things

1. Have an endless loop (`while(true)`) in place of a fixed loop (`for(;;)`)
2. Re-populate the array with the original list of words when you get to `awesome.`

Here's one way to achieve that - I have just C/P the array but there is a smarter way to do that - which I'll leave to your imagination.

```js
var i, word, rnd, words, fadeSpeed, timer;

words = ['respected​.', 'essential.', 'tactical.', 'effortless.', 'credible.', 'smart.', 'engaging.', 'focused.', 'effective.', 'clear.', 'relevant.', 'strategic.', 'trusted.', 'compelling.', 'admired.', 'inspiring.', 'cogent.', 'impactful.', 'valued.'];

fadeSpeed = 500;
timer = 2000;

while(true){
  var word;
  if(words.length == 0){
      word = "awesome.";  
      words = ['respected​.', 'essential.', 'tactical.', 'effortless.', 'credible.', 'smart.', 'engaging.', 'focused.', 'effective.', 'clear.', 'relevant.', 'strategic.', 'trusted.', 'compelling.', 'admired.', 'inspiring.', 'cogent.', 'impactful.', 'valued.'];
  }
  else{
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    word = words[rnd];
    words.splice(rnd, 1);
  }
  (function(word) {
        $('h1.random em').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
                $(this).html(word);
            })
            .slideDown('slow')
            .delay(timer)
            .fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    })(word);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="random"><em></em></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the while loop seems to be broken. I can't load the page after adding the script update. I removed that code and refreshed and the page loads again.